# Inject service to model

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a TypeScript class - business object model:

```
module app.domain {

    export interface IDefect {
        defectId: number;
        comment: string;
    }

    export class Defect implements IDefect {
        defectId: number;
        comment: string;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to inject AngularJS service to this model to use it in model's methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Just using the $inject syntax. e.g. :

```
class Service
{
    static $inject = ['$http'];    
    constructor( private $http: ng.IHttpService )
    {
    }

    public MyMethod()
    {
        this.$http.get( "/" )
            .success( null )
            .error( null );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to create a domain object, and not a service.
Services in Angular are singletons (One per app). To be able to do `new` on an injected object you have to define it as a [Factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)